# SQL Server 2012 Lag and Lead Function

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, lag, lead

SQL Server 2012 `Lag` and `Lead` functions aren't performing well over large amounts of data, ~100 million records with ~200 columns.

The combination of

```
lag(balance, 1, 0) over (partition by loanId order by datetime series)
```

trying to get previous date's balance. The execution plan says most time consuming part falls in (order by) part.

Is there a way to improve the performance?

Comment: can you put up the whole select statement.

Answer (score 3):

You can improve the performance by having an index on `(loanid, datatime series)`.